# How to insert background image to my website?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a background image into my website using `css`, but it's not working. I'm taking the picture and putting it into the same folder that I have my `.html` and `.css` file, but it's not working.  Here is my `css` code I'm using.

```
html { 
   background: ("/storage/emulated/0/My_webpage/1.jpg")
}
```

I'm doing this on my phone using quick edit as my code editor. Thanks

Comment: Which folder is your css located in? Are you calling the image from your css file or in your html inside a `<style>` element? Also, you should style onto the `<body>` element and not the `<html>` element.

Comment: @Dade please post image full path

Comment: Hi, I made a folder on my phone storage named "My webpage", inside that folder is my "main.html" and "main.css" files. Also I put the image I want to use as a background "1.jpg" in that folder. I tried calling the image from css using this, html { background-image: URL ("path stated above") } I also tried doing this in the html file using <style>, and changed html to "body". When I click details on the photo I'm wanting to use it says " /storage/emulated/0/My webpage/1.jpg" wich is what I'm imputing as the url. Also in css I'm puting an underscore between "My_webpage"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> ".\storage\emulated\0\My_webpage\1.jpg"

Or you can Debug console by browser tool. e.g, Chrome - F12.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead..  in the body tag try 
  *  < body background="URL" > *

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like this. `background-image: url("whateverThePictureIs.png");`

Comment: `background` is a shorthand for all `background-*` properties. This won't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   body {
        background-image: url("/storage/emulated/0/My_webpage/1.jpg");
    }
```